# making a digital dice

Tags: arduino-uno

i'm trying to make a digital dice to play catan with, here's what i have so far

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <DFR_LCD_Keypad.h>

// this is factory config shield initialisation
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);

// initialise the keypad
DFR_LCD_Keypad keypad(A0, &lcd);
int lcd_key     = 0;
int abc_key_in;
int read_LCD_buttons;
int  diceOne;
int  diceTwo;
#define btnSELECT 4
int read_LCD_buttons()
{
  abc_key_in = analogRead(0);
if (abc_key_in < 790) return btnSELECT;}
const int button = 4;
const int BUTTON4LOW = 400;
const int BUTTON4HIGH = 650;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Press to dice");
  pinMode (A0, INPUT);
  i
}

void loop() {
  int reading =  analogRead (A0);

  lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();

 if (reading<BUTTON4LOW && reading<BUTTON4HIGH) {
    diceOne = random(1, 7);
    diceTwo = random(1, 7);


  if (diceOne + diceTwo == 7) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
    lcd.print("7");
    lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
    lcd.print("The pirate");



      if (diceOne + diceTwo == 3,2,1,5,4,6) {
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
          lcd.print("fish");
      }
      }
  }
}
}
```

and im running into a error code saying

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows Store 1.8.10.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

demo_simple:15: error: 'int read_LCD_buttons()' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 int read_LCD_buttons()
                      ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino:11:5: note: previous declaration 'int read_LCD_buttons'
 int read_LCD_buttons;
     ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino: In function 'int read_LCD_buttons()':
demo_simple:15: error: 'int read_LCD_buttons()' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 int read_LCD_buttons()
                      ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino:11:5: note: previous declaration 'int read_LCD_buttons
 int read_LCD_buttons;
     ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino: In function 'void setup()':
demo_simple:28: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
   i
   ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino: In function 'void loop()':
demo_simple:34: error: 'read_LCD_buttons' cannot be used as a function
   lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();
                              ^
C:\Users\taran\Desktop\arduino\demo_simple\demo_simple.ino: At global scope:
demo_simple:58: error: expected declaration before '}' token
 }
 ^
exit status 1
'int read_LCD_buttons()' redeclared as different kind of symbol
```

Comment: name your children, like `int x read_LCD_buttons()`. also, that will play the same game each time, you need to randomize, preferably with micros() after each user input.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
int read_LCD_buttons;

int read_LCD_buttons()
{
//..
}
```

You can't have a variable `int read_LCD_buttons` at the same time as a function called `read_LCD_buttons` -- this identifier is already taken. It looks however like you're not assigning or reading anything from this variable, so it probably never should have existed in the first place -- deletion is the solution.

In the case that you wanted to write a function prototype (which you by the way don't have to write in the Arduino IDE because it autogenerates them), the correct form would have been

```
int read_LCD_buttons();
```

i.e., the exact same prototype ended by a `;`.

In `setup()` you have a random `i` which doesn't belong there.

```
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Press to dice");
  pinMode (A0, INPUT);
  i //delete this line
}
```

Finally, you have a mismatch of opening and closing curly braces. Always format your code correctly, so that these errors are more easily spotted! You have one final `}` too much.

```
void loop() {
  int reading = analogRead(A0);

  lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();

  if (reading < BUTTON4LOW && reading < BUTTON4HIGH) {
    diceOne = random(1, 7);
    diceTwo = random(1, 7);

    if (diceOne + diceTwo == 7) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
      lcd.print("7");
      lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
      lcd.print("The pirate");

      if (diceOne + diceTwo == 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
        lcd.print("fish");
      }
    }
  }
}
} //This } is too much!
```

Then you'll also see that the third `if` statment which checks for a sum is actually within another expression where it was asserted that the sum is already 7. Then the inner `if` can never become true. You probably meant to move the `if` to the outer part, i.e. write

```
void loop() {
  int reading = analogRead(A0);

  lcd_key = read_LCD_buttons();

  if (reading < BUTTON4LOW && reading < BUTTON4HIGH) {
    diceOne = random(1, 7);
    diceTwo = random(1, 7);

    if (diceOne + diceTwo == 7) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
      lcd.print("7");
      lcd.setCursor(3, 1);
      lcd.print("The pirate");
    }
    //the line below is still wrong
    if (diceOne + diceTwo == 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
      lcd.print("fish");
    }
  }
}
```

Next, this expression makes no sense.

```
if (diceOne + diceTwo == 3,2,1,5,4,6)
```

I think you meant that "if the sum of diceOne and diceTwo are equal to either 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, or 6 (i.e. within 1 and 6 inclusive), then do something.

Using multiple or statments this would be expressed as

```
if ((diceOne + diceTwo == 3) || (diceOne + diceTwo == 2) || (diceOne + diceTwo == 1) || (diceOne + diceTwo == 5) ||(diceOne + diceTwo == 4) || (diceOne + diceTwo == 6))
```

Or using the simpler interval check, assuming both numbers are positive and greater than 1.

```
if( diceOne + diceTwo <= 6)
```

Also this expression is suspect

```
if (reading<BUTTON4LOW && reading<BUTTON4HIGH)
```

When you have a LOW and a HIGH boundary and you want to check if `reading` is between these, you would write it as "if reading is greater than the lower boundary and less than the higher boundary", i.e.,

```
if (reading > BUTTON4LOW && reading < BUTTON4HIGH)
```

Comment: I fixed my errors but I want to be able to press the select button on the LCD keypad shield to generate random numbers, how would I do that (coding)

Comment: and I want to press the select button once for the two dice and again for the 1 die

Comment: @user46194 This is not a free coding service. Work it out yourself, and, if you have a particular problem on why something you wrote doesn't work, you can ask another question.